# How to install scrapyd 1.2.1 on ubuntu for all users?

Tags: pip, scrapyd

I am trying to install scrapyd on ubuntu 18.04. Therefore I did a

```
pip3 install scrapyd
```

Somehow it is now installed under my local directory:

```
merlin@spider1:~$ scrapyd
2020-05-03T15:16:17+0200 [-] Loading /home/merlin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapyd/txapp.py...
2020-05-03T15:16:17+0200 [-] Scrapyd web console available at http://127.0.0.1:6800/
2020-05-03T15:16:17+0200 [-] Loaded.
```

Looking for the conf file:

```
merlin@spider1:~$ locate scrapyd.conf
/home/merlin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapyd/default_scrapyd.conf
```

I tried it a second time:

```
merlin@spider1:~$ sudo pip3 install scrapyd
The directory '/home/merlin/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/merlin/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting scrapyd
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/c0/0aaadd16155743b1d0d0b6300286845e5b9871acbde274365c7b4c0a8148/scrapyd-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: Scrapy>=1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: Twisted>=8.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: protego>=0.1.15 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity>=16.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: queuelib>=1.4.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.1.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: parsel>=1.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect>=0.9.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL>=16.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Twisted>=8.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Twisted>=8.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Twisted>=8.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Twisted>=8.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest!=1.10.0,>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Twisted>=8.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Twisted>=8.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.1.3->Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.0->Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted>=8.0->scrapyd)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.0->Scrapy>=1.0->scrapyd)
Installing collected packages: scrapyd
Successfully installed scrapyd-1.2.1
```

This somehow does not work:

```
$ scrapyd
-bash: /home/merlin/.local/bin/scrapyd: No such file or directory
```

How do I get scraypd installed under /etc/scrapyd ?

Comment: I think these two lines tell the problem `The directory '/home/merlin/.cache/pip/http' or its....` `The directory '/home/merlin/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not....`. In the end of both lines said `If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag`.

Comment: Yes that solved it.

Comment: Can you add your solution as the answer? I think this will helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

This has fixed the issue for me: `sudo -H  pip3 install scrapyd`